# Differentiate functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions

I have two functions:

```
F1[t_, g_] := a1*t + a2*g

F2[t_, g_] := b1*t + b2*g
```

I want to evaluate $(dt/dF1)_{F2}$; i.e., differentiate $t$ over $F1$ when $F2$ is held constant. Is there any straightforward way in *Mathematica* to do that with `D`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not used to your notation, but does this give you what you mean?

```
Block[{a1, a2, b1, b2},
 SetAttributes[{a1, a2, b1, b2}, Constant];
 Dt[t]/Dt[f1] /. First@Solve[
     {Dt[f1] == Dt[F1[t, g]], 0 == Dt[F2[t, g]]},
     {Dt[f1], Dt[t]}] // Simplify
 ]
(*  b2/(-a2 b1 + a1 b2)  *)
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much